# function to create grade dictionary

Tags: python

I'm writing a function that its input is a text file as below:

```
1000123456, Rubble, Test_3,  80, Test_4 , 80
1000123459, Chipmunk, Test_4, 96, Test_1, 86 , Quiz_1 , 88
```

the desired output is as below:

```
{'1000123456': ['Rubble', 0, 0, 80, 80, 40.0], '1000123459': ['Chipmunk', 86, 0, 0, 96, 45.5]}
```

the key of the dictionary is student ID. i have written the below code:

```py
def create_grades_dict(a='students_grades.txt'):
    my_dictionary={}
    new_list=[]
    my_file=open(a,'r')
    data=my_file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        student_ID=line.strip().split(",")
        new_list= line.strip().split(",")        
        my_dictionary[student_ID[0]]=[]
        new_list.pop(0)
        new_list.sort()
        print(new_list)
        for i in new_list :
            my_dictionary[student_ID[0]]+=[ i]
```

my output is:

```
{'1000123456': ['  80', ' 80', ' Rubble', ' Test_3', ' Test_4 '], '1000123459': [' 86 ', ' 88', ' 96', ' Chipmunk', ' Quiz_1 ', ' Test_1', ' Test_4']}
```

the desired output is as below:

```
{'1000123456': ['Rubble', 0, 0, 80, 80, 40.0], '1000123459': ['Chipmunk', 86, 0, 0, 96, 45.5]}
```

now my problem is that as desired out_put says TEST_1 THROUGH TEST_4 is important for us and any other marks should be omitted, how to do that? or if any of these 4 test marks doesn't exist the mark should be considered zero.

Comment: Could you please format your question properly?

Comment: How do you determine which columns have 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following piece of code:

```
def create_grades_dict(a='students_grades.txt'):
my_dictionary={}
my_file=open(a,'r')
data=my_file.readlines()
for line in data:
    new_list= line.strip().split(",")
    my_dictionary[new_list[0]]=[new_list[1]]
    tmp_dict = {'Test_1':0,'Test_2':0, 'Test_3':0, 'Test_4':0}
    for  i in range(2,len(new_list),2):
        if new_list[i].strip() in tmp_dict:
            tmp_dict[new_list[i].strip()] = int(new_list[i + 1].strip())
    tmp=0
    for i in range(1,5):
        my_dictionary[new_list[0]].append(tmp_dict['Test_'+str(i)])
        tmp += tmp_dict['Test_'+str(i)]
    my_dictionary[new_list[0]].append(tmp/4)
print(my_dictionary)
```

It should be ok while the following assumptions are correct:
1. First item in line is allways student_id
2. Second item in line is allways a word (Chipmunk, Rubble)
3. The rest of items going in pairs "key value"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first entry is the student ID, and the second is the name(?), this code should work:

```
def create_grades_dict(a='students_grades.txt'):
my_dictionary={}
my_file=open(a,'r')
data=my_file.readlines()
for line in data:
    data_list = line.strip().split(",")
    student_ID = data_list.pop(0).strip()
    student_name = data_list.pop(0).strip()
    test_scores = [0] * 4
    while data_list:
        item = data_list.pop(0).strip()
        if 'Test' in item:
            test_scores[int(item[-1]) - 1] = int(data_list.pop(0))

    avg_score = sum(test_scores) / len(test_scores)

    my_dictionary[student_ID] = [student_name] + test_scores + [avg_score]
return my_dictionary
```